# Wrong path paths in .css (result of export Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I faced with next issue. As the result of the next export, I receive wrong paths in CSS files, for example:

```
background: url(/images/oval_21.webp)
```

but should be

```
background: url(../../../images/oval_21.webp)
```

The same thing happens with fonts. Also I need to note I am using 'next-optimized-images' for handling images in export and here my config setup:

```
module.exports = withPlugins([
  [optimizedImages, {
    optimizeImages: false,
  }],
  {
    assetPrefix: isDeployMode ? '.' : '',
    reactStrictMode: true,
    experimental: { esmExternals: true },
    env: {
      CQ_USE_ANALYTICS: JSON.stringify(config.useAnalytics),
      CQ_AMPLITUDE_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(config.amplitudeApiKey),
    },
    images: {
      domains: ["localhost"],
    },
  }
]);
```

This CSS rule used in the Sass file:

```
#cq-landing {
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
  font-display: swap;
  background: url(/images/oval_21.webp) top 0 center no-repeat;
  ...
}
```

And everything works fine with `next dev` and `next start`, issue reproduces only after export in static files.

Comment: Can you add snippet from your code where you are using and importing image?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the head message, but anyway, this image was used in the Sass and imported into the main Sass file for further import. Also, I need to note that everything is ok on next start and next dev.

Comment: Where are your images located? Can you not moved them to the `public` folder?

Comment: They are in the public/images folder.
Tags <img src=''> - works properly but CSS are not.